# Paramiko on OpenWRT 22.03

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, openwrt

I seem to be having trouble getting Paramiko to run despite all the dependencies I think it needs installed.  Whenever I try to import it the following traceback occurs:

```
Python 3.10.9 (main, Sep 11 2023, 08:28:47) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 135, in <module>
class Transport(threading.Thread, ClosingContextManager):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 209, in Transport
if KexCurve25519.is_available():
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 30, in is_available
X25519PrivateKey.generate()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py", line 39, in generate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 113, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so: ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string: symbol not found
```

So it appears to be missing a call in the library.  These are the installed dependencies:

```
Package      Version
------------ -------
bcrypt       3.2.2
bottle       0.12.19
cffi         1.16.0
cryptography 3.4.8
hanip        2.11
ifaddr       0.1.7
netifaces    0.10.9
paho-mqtt    1.6.1
paramiko     3.0.0
pip          23.0.1
ply          3.11
pycparser    2.21
PyNaCl       1.5.0
pyOpenSSL    24.0.0
pyserial     3.4
setuptools   65.5.0
six          1.16.0
xmltodict    0.12.0
zeroconf     0.21.3
```

I am using Python 3.10 on OpenWRT22.03 running on mips.  Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated.